# How to save video to gallery and retrieve the saved video uri?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediastore

I am trying to make a save to gallery feature for my app. My app's minimum api level is 21 and max 30.
Here is the code I am using for saving video to gallery. Everything works perfect but the code only works for API 29 and Above. Here is the code:

```
String videoFileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

                 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                     ContentValues valuesvideos;
                     valuesvideos = new ContentValues();
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + "Folder");
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
                     ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
                     Uri collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
                     Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);
                     ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
                     try {
                         assert uriSavedVideo != null;
                         parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo, "w");
                         assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
                         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "Application" + File.separator + "video.mp4");
                         byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                         int len;
                         while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                             out.write(buf, 0, len);
                         }
                         out.close();
                         in.close();
                         parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     valuesvideos.clear();
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
                     context.getContentResolver().update(uriSavedVideo, valuesvideos, null, null);
                 }
```

This is the code I use for Versions below API 29:

```
ContentValues valuesvideos;
                     valuesvideos = new ContentValues();
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "Folder");
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                     valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                     ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
                     Uri collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                     Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);
                     ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
                     try {
                         assert uriSavedVideo != null;
                         parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo, "w");
                         assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
                         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "Application" + File.separator + "video.mp4");
                         byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                         int len;
                         while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                             out.write(buf, 0, len);
                         }
                         out.close();
                         in.close();
                         parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     valuesvideos.clear();
                     context.getContentResolver().update(uriSavedVideo, valuesvideos, null, null);
```

How to write this exact function for lower APIs? Now I have tried MediaScanner but it seems too slow and I can't get the uri of the saved file. Hope you will answer. Regards.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220684/discussion-on-question-by-webdiva-how-to-save-video-to-gallery-and-retrieve-the).